# Rate This App - iOS

Tags: iphone

### Can i use the same "rate this App" URL for an updated version of the app?

Eg: **itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=12345698**

*So in the above example, if i have already used this above URL for version 1.0 of my app.
1. Can i use the same URL for the Updated Version 1.1 of the app ?
2. Will this URL work once v1.1 of the app is uploaded on App Store ?
3. or will the ID number change incase of newer app version ? *

Comment: yes you can use that url in updated version.:)

Comment: Thank you for confirming ..